# merging parts (branches) of associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I seem to get stuck at a (at first glance) simple thing:
I have a nested assoc array i.e.

```
"stock" => [
    123 => [
            3 => 17,
            5 => 5,
            7 => 0
        ],
    456 => [
            3 => 1,
            5 => 3,
            7 => 7
        ]
]
```

These represent stocks of items (123 and 456) in warehouses (3, 5 and 7).
Now I want to update stock in one warehouse for one item i.e.

```
"stock" => [
    123 => [
            3 => 11
        ]
]
```

I have tried to approach this via array_merge (re-keys the array) and array_merge_recursive (strangely does the same while it shouldn't - are numeric keys the reason?) but to no avail. Also I found this interesting bit https://vancelucas.com/blog/php-array_merge-preserving-numeric-keys/ but that replaces the entire branch of the array (so I'm losing warehouses 5 and 7).

Does anyone have some clever idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
$newArray = array_replace_recursive($sourceArray, $newDataArray);
```

Fiddle here https://3v4l.org/qdejB

Comment: perfect solution for my case. It doesn't care about the depth of the branch, so it can change anytime.I was hoping for an actual built-in php-function :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is your snippet,

```
foreach ($temp['stock'] as $key => &$value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        // no need to check, it will add at respective key matching
        $arr['stock'][$key][$key1] = $value1;    
    }
}
```

[**working demo**](https://3v4l.org/1tFgG).

Comment: Thanky you for this answer. The actual array is a bit more complex than my example - I should have mentioned that. So I was looking for a more generalized way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but nothing seems to be able to stop you from:

```
$foo['stock'][123][3] = 11;
```

Comment: You're right. :) But I'd have to explode and extract the branch (of varying depth - the actual array is a bit more complex than my example, should have mentioned this).